# Prolog: Redirect system output

Tags: prolog, try-catch

There are Prolog predicates that output error messages, like `load_files/1` in case the file could not be found:

```
error(existence_error(source_sink,'/home/foo/nothinghere.txt'),_3724).
```

These error messages are just printed to stdout but are not returned as prolog return value.

In my case, `load_files/1` gets called deep down as part of a procedure that I don't want to modify. I just deliver the file name and wait for the return value. But as far as I understand, the return value, in this case, is either True or an error. Is there any way for me to redirect the error output to the return value so that I can actually do something with the output I am getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `catch/3`.

```
?- catch(load_files('/tmp/exists.prolog'), E, true).
true.

?- catch(load_files('/tmp/notexists.prolog'), E, true).
E = error(existence_error(source_sink, '/tmp/notexists.prolog'), _).
```

`catch(:Goal, +Catcher, :Recover)` is used for catching `throw(_)` from the `:Goal`.

1. `Catcher` is unified with the argument of `throw/1`.
2. `Recover` is called using `call/1`.

In the above example `E` unifies with any error. We do not want that, so we can do something like:

```
catchFileErrors(G, F) :-
    catch(G, error(existence_error(source_sink, F), _), true).
```

```
?- catchFileErrors(load_files('exists.prolog'), E).
true.

?- catchFileErrors(load_files('notexists.prolog'), E).
E = 'notexists.prolog'.
```

You can pass a goal as the last argument to catch if you have a strategy to recover from the error.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!